# Laravel Rutas y métodos

Tags: php, laravel

Con Laravel no me permite usar el método según la variable del array "access" (esta puede variar a login, signup u otras...), el problema es que no carga ningún controlador o método, que necesito para establecer a donde debe ir.

La opción de crear una ruta para cada método (no me vale).

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/app

{"access":"login", "first_name_in": "Bruce", "last_name_in":"Wayne" , "email_in":"batman@jla.com","password_in":12345678}

Route::post('voice/login', function (Request $request) {

    switch ($request->access) {
      case 'login':

        $out = redirect()->action('AccessController@login',[$request]);
        //$out = json_encode('login');
        return $out;
        break;

      case 'signup':

        $out = json_encode('signup');
        return $out;
        break;

      default:
        $out = json_encode('fallo');
        return $out;
        break;
    }

  });
```

Comment: puedes ejecutar `php artisasn route:list` y nos muestras como tienes `voice\login`?

Comment: +--------+----------+-----------------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI             | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /               |      | Closure | web        |
|        | POST     | api/voice/login |      | Closure | api        |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------+---------+------------+

Comment: te devuelve algún error al hacer la solicitud? porque como veo los métodos son solo `GET|HEAD`. en caso en que no te devuelve ningún error abre la ventana de inspección de tu navegador y mira la solicitud `voice/login` que respuesta te devuelve.

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
Action App\Http\Controllers\AccessController@login not defined.

Comment: Según lo que haya en la variable del array json, debo acceder a un método u otro además de pasar la información del array a ese método.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu método AccessController? recibe algún argumento?

Comment: public function access(Request $request)
    {

            $user = User::where('id',$request->first_name_in)->select('name','id','email','coin')->get();

      $data = array(
              'id'   => $user->id,
              'username' => $user->user_name,
              'coin' => $user->coin
             );

      return json_encode($data);
    }

Comment: Estas llamando a AccessController en vez de access

Comment: Nombre de controlador y método, teniendo en cuenta que posiblemente tenga que llamar a otro controlador cuando la variable access lo pida...

Answer (score 0):

Según to método access

```
public function access(Request $request) { 
  $user = User::where('id',$request->first_name_in)->select('name','id','email','coin')->get(); 
  $data = array( 'id' => $user->id, 'username' => $user->user_name, 'coin' =>$user->coin ); 
  return json_encode($data); 
}
```

pero lo estas llamando por AccessController, de esta manera tu Closure no puede encontrar AccessController porque en realidad no existe, asi que tienes que cambiar el nombre del método:

```
Route::post('voice/login', function (Request $request) {

switch ($request->access) {
  case 'login':

    $out = redirect()->action('access@login',[$request]);
    //$out = json_encode('login');
    return $out;
    break;

  case 'signup':

    $out = json_encode('signup');
    return $out;
    break;

  default:
    $out = json_encode('fallo');
    return $out;
    break;
}

});
```

O bien cambiar tu método `public function access`por `AccessController`.
espero que te ayudé.

Comment: No funciona el cambio! me sigue saliendo el error de controlador no definido si lo llamo dentro de una función